# how to display message error when authentication failed (account not yet activated)?

Tags: php, symfony

I have to check, at the time of connection, if the user's account is activated. To do this, I check that he no longer has an activation token.

```
namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAccountStatusException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class UserChecker implements UserCheckerInterface
{
    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return;
        }

        if(!empty($user->getActivationToken())){
            throw new CustomUserMessageAccountStatusException('Your user account is not activated');
        }
    }

    public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to display the error message 'Your user account is not activated' on the login page. How do I do this through the onAuthenticationFailure method of my custom authentication class?

```
class Authenticator extends AbstractAuthenticator
{
public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): ?Response
    {
        // on failure, throw the exception
        throw $exception;
    } 
}
```

And in particular by relying on my login template thus configured.

```
{% if error %}
<div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

My SecurityController :

```
class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the way you follow is totally correct but even if the users did not submit the confirmation message, their accounts will be authenticated but here is your role to remember them that they have not confirmed their acoounts yet.